# Dynamic Background around a header with background

Tags: html, css, background

I got a pretty serious problem.

I have a header with a background, which has different ends left and right. 
The header, content as well as a wrapper around them are all 1065px wide.

I created another "background_wrapper" which holds a graphic that continues on the header graphic. It features the different ends left and right and empty space, as wide as the header graphic. It has to stay right at the end of the header graphic, as it is when the browser window is 100% wide (on a PC screen). However, if I resize it, it will gets smaller and smaller (everytime on 100%), so it moves behind the header.

**I uploaded it here: http://bf3zone.bplaced.net/Coding/**

My code for it:

```
    <body>
<div id="background_addition">
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html" title="M3 Institut - Zurück zum Start">
                <img src="images/logo_hover.png" alt="M3 Institut - Menschen machen Märkte" class="b" />
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="a" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" title="Start" class="current_page_item">Start</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tab 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tab 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tab 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tab 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My css for all my stuff containing body/header/wrapper:

```
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    } 

html, body {
    display: block; 
    background: url(images/background.jpg) repeat-x; 
    font: normal 100% Arial, sans-serif; /* 16px */ 
    line-height: 140%;
    color: #464646; 
    clear: both; 
    }

html, body, #wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

body > #wrapper {
    height: auto; 
    min-height: 100%;
    }

#wrapper {
    width: 1065px;
    }

#background_addition {
background: url(images/wrapper.png) no-repeat center top;
}

#header {
width: 1065px;
height: 193px;
background: url(images/header_background.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Adding a min-width to your body with the width of the header works.

```
html, body {
      min-width: 1064px;
      }
```